# Replacement of particular number in unix files

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I want to make a command that can replace a particular number in Unix file system for example:

```
ZAR     ZEC      ZDA
-9         2      3
4          8      -9
5          6      7
```

I have  `ZAR`, `ZEC`, `ZDA`  as my header and **-9 in `ZDA` must be replaced by +9**. What command should I write so it will change in particular that number without changing others value like "-9" present in `ZAR` field?

Comment: Hi tomas I want to change in original file awk will just print output

Answer (score 3):

To change any occurrence of `-9` in the third column of your file to `+9`:

```
$ awk '$3==-9 {$3="+9"} 1' OFS='\t' file
ZAR     ZEC     ZDA
-9      2       3
4       8       +9
5       6       7
```

`$3==-9` selects lines for which the third column is `-9`.  For those lines, the assignment `$3="+9"` changes that column to `+9`.  The `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.  Lastly, `OFS='\t'` tells awk to print the output using a tab as the field separator.

#### Changing the file in place

Using GNU awk (Linux):

```
awk -i inplace '$3==-9 {$3="+9"} 1' OFS='\t' file
```

Using BSD/OSX awk:

```
awk '$3==-9 {$3="+9"} 1' OFS='\t' file >tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: print (without arguments) is less cryptic and more portable than just 1.

Comment: @citrin _"more portable"_  Are you aware of any version of `awk` that does not use `{print}` as the default action for a condition?

Comment: I thought 1 don't work with one-true-awk (used in FreeBSD), but it woks. Anyway `{ print }` is more readable.

Comment: @user3476203 I just edited this answer to show how to use awk to change the original file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
ZAR     ZEC      ZDA
-9         2      3
4          8      -9
5          6      7
```

Since the `ZDA` column happens to be last field,

```
$ sed 's/-9$/+9/' file
ZAR     ZEC      ZDA
-9         2      3
4          8      +9
5          6      7
```

To change the input file itself, use `-i` for GNU version (or `-i.bak` on OSX/BSD)

```
sed -i 's/-9$/+9/' file
```